# Can not download every video I've gotten from api youtube for Java Android?

Tags: java, android, api, download, youtube

I did setOnClickListner for every video in adapter I've gotten from api youtube. I am able to download some videos to storage but when I do the same with some more videos it cannot though all video is displayed in my recyclerview. My code:

```
String youtubeLink = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoYT.getId().getVideoId());
YouTubeUriExtractor ytEx = new YouTubeUriExtractor(context) {
                        @Override
                        public void onUrisAvailable(String videoId, String videoTitle, SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles) {
                            if (ytFiles != null) {
                                int itag = 22;
                                if(ytFiles.get(itag)!=null){
                                    String downloadURL = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
                                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadURL));
                                    String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(downloadURL,null,null);
                                    request.setTitle(title);
                                    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                                    String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(downloadURL);
                                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookie);
                                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,title);
                                    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Bắt đầu tải xuống...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    ytEx.execute(youtubeLink);
```

Comment: Does this code generate some sort of error or message telling why certain videos are not downloaded?

Comment: Android Studio gives no message or error but I think every time a video is downloaded the line ```ytFiles.get(itag)``` return to null

Comment: perhaps if you you `System.out` to print the result of the line you suspect to the console you will know if it returns null or not.